# Equivalence of simply connected domain

Tags: complex-analysis, homotopy-theory

I'm reading the lecture notes of my teacher and he defines

$\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ is a simply connected domain if every two pairs of curves with the same initial and final point are homotopic.

He then says that this definition is equivalent to the statement that every loop is homotopic to a point.

Any idea on how to prove this? I know how to prove $\implies$ since the latter is like a special case of the former.

Comment: How can you get a loop from two curves having the same initial and final point ?

Comment: Reverting one of the curves I think

Comment: Exactly ! Then you get a homotopy between this loop and a constant curve as a starting point

Comment: Of course, you will need to twist it a bit if you want a homotopy between the curves, fixing the endpoints.